# 21:9, 2560x1080 with AMD card

Tags: 18.04, graphics, amd-graphics, monitor

I have a pc with 18.04 (xfce) and an ATI/AMD 4550 card. My monitor has a native resolution of 2560x1080, but so far I've just managed to get 1920x1080 from the 4550.

This is the output of xrandr -q:

[image]

Note that this machine has two nvidia cards also (for computing purposes) and they are able to provide 2560x1080 over the same hdmi cable without any fuss.

Answer (score 6):

You can create mode resolution using `xrandr` and `gtf`

First use gtf to create a mode line

```
gtf 2560 1080 60
```

this will generate something like this

```
# 2560x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 230.76 MHz
  Modeline "2560x1080_60.00"  230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
```

then create a new mode using xrandr and parameters from previous command

```
 xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60" 230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
```

Now you need to add the mode to the desired output, in your case it seems to be `HDMI-0`

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_60
```

Finally apply the new mode

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_60
```

Cheers

Comment: excellent solution. If this doesn't work for someone try reducing the refresh rate to 50hz.

Comment: Looks like `GTF` is an older. You can use `CVT` for the same purpose: `cvt 2560 1080 60` will generate a better sync.